# Прописная или строчная буква?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В выражении "ящик (П)андоры" — с какой буквы писать? Понятно, что "Пандора" — имя собственное, но тут ведь в переносном значении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неважно, что Пандора употребляется в переносном значении. Имя собственное все равно пишется с прописной буквы: между Сциллой и Харибдой,приносить жертвы Молоху и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

С заглавной, естественно.
Здесь переносное значение относится ко всему выражению "ящик Пандоры", но не к Пандоре как таковой. Внутри таких фразеологизмов составляющие сохраняют исходное написание.